# "Read More" for Django WYSIWYG editor

Tags: python, html, django, wysiwyg, summernote

I am using `django-summernote` editor for creating posts with text and images which are saved in a character field as HTML tags.

I want to add a *read-more* functionality where a limited sized preview is shown for all the posts. An idea could be to truncate the character field, but it may lead to truncation of HTML image tags if they happen to be positioned between the boundary.

How to get around this?

Comment: Mind explaining reason for downvotes?

Comment: Asking for advice or recommendations isn't the purpose of the site; you need to ask a specific programming problem which has an objective best answer. Good luck :)

Comment: I ain't asking for advice, rather looking for a way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django has two template filters you can use to make sure your HTML doesn't get malformed: [truncatechars_html](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars-html) and [truncatewords_html](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatewords-html)

Template filters are just functions, so you can import them anywhere you need in your Python code and assign the result to a variable you can use elsewhere, etc.

Example:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import truncatechars_html

html = """<p>Look, I&#8217;m some HTML. You can truncate me
       with Django template filters</p>"""
truncated_value = truncatechars_html(html, 30)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to this party but this post came up in search results. I just got a working solution to this myself with a custom template filter. This allows you to drop in the break on a case by case basis like WordPress. Here is what I did (with help from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633932/slice-a-string-after-a-certain-phrase) and the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters)):

Sample post submitted in a textfield:

```
<p>Here is some sample text</p> 
<!--more-->
<img src="cool_photo.jpg" />
```

in templatetags/read_more.py

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='read_more')
@stringfilter
def read_more(value):
    pattern = "<!--more-->"
    return value.split(pattern, 1)[0]
```

in the template that's rendering the truncated version:

```
{% load read_more %}
{{ object.body|read_more|safe }}
```

Since the split pattern is an html comment there's no need to cut it from the main post body template:

```
{{ object.body|safe }}
```