# How to split a string and keeping the pattern

Tags: python

This is how the string splitting works for me right now:

```
output = string.encode('UTF8').split('}/n}')[0]
output += '}\n}'
```

But I am wondering if there is a more pythonic way to do it.

The goal is to get everything before this **'}/n}'** including **'}/n}'**.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. What is your input and expected output?

Comment: @OrangeFlash81: I am trying to get everything before '}/n}' but could not find a better way to do it as stated above.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! I don't know of any better way of doing it, but there may well be one.

Comment: Are you trying to get a substring from the beginning of the string up to the '}/n}'?

Comment: If you ad something like this, it would greatly help: input is "xxxxxxxxx". expected output is "yyyyyyyyyy"

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good use of [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition).

```
string = '012za}/n}ddfsdfk'

parts = string.partition('}/n}')
# ('012za', '}/n}', 'ddfsdfk')

''.join(parts[:-1])
# 012za}/n}
```

Or, you can find it explicitly with [`str.index`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.index).

```
repl = '}/n}'

string[:string.index(repl) + len(repl)]
# 012za}/n}
```

This is probably better than using [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) since an exception will be raised if the substring isn't found, rather than producing nonsensical results.

It seems like anything "more elegant" would require regular expressions.

```
import re
re.search('(.*?}/n})', string).group(0)
# 012za}/n}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with with `re.split()` -- the key is putting parens around the split pattern to preserve what you split on:

```
import re

output = "".join(re.split(r'(}/n})', string.encode('UTF8'))[:2])
```

However, I doubt that this is either the most efficient nor most Pythonic way to achieve what you want.  I.e. I don't think this is naturally a *split* sort of problem.  For example:

```
tag = '}/n}'

encoded = string.encode('UTF8')

output = encoded[:encoded.index(tag)] + tag
```

or if you insist on a one-liner:

```
output = (lambda string, tag: string[:string.index(tag)] + tag)(string.encode('UTF8'), '}/n}')
```

or returning to regex:

```
output = re.match(r".*}/n}", string.encode('UTF8')).group(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> string_to_split = 'first item{\n{second item'
>>> sep = '{\n{'
>>> output = [item + sep for item in string_to_split.split(sep)]
NOTE: output = ['first item{\n{', 'second item{\n{']
```

then you can use the result:

```
for item_with_delimiter in output:
    ...
```

It might be useful to look up `os.linesep` if you're not sure what the line ending will be. `os.linesep` is whatever the line ending is under your current OS, so `'\r\n'` under Windows or `'\n'` under Linux or Mac. It depends where input data is from, and how flexible your code needs to be across environments.

Answer (score -1):

Adapted from [Slice a string after a certain phrase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633932/slice-a-string-after-a-certain-phrase), you can combine find and slice to get the first part of the string and retain `}/n}`.

```
str = "012za}/n}ddfsdfk"
str[:str.find("}/n}")+4]
```

Will result in `012za}/n}`

Comment: Wasn't me, but there is an obvious typo, it should be `str[:str.find...]` instead of `str[str:str.find...]`. Also, `str.find` behaves oddly when a match isn't found, -1 + 4 = 3.

Comment: yup i couldn't cut-n-paste from console and didn't realize I had typed it 2x